# Telethon client.conversation() won't work

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, telethon

Hi Im realy desperate...

I try to make a quiz like conversation with a telegram bot using telethon.
It should be looking like:

```
user1 > /start
bot > Hello who send you?
user1 > user0
bot > Thank you. So do you want in channel1 or channel2 or both?
user1 > channel1
*Bot invites the user
```

I used this example:
https://arabic-telethon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extra/examples/telegram-client.html#conversations-waiting-for-messages-or-replies
Example code:

```
with bot.conversation(chat) as conv:
    conv.send_message('Hi!')
    hello = conv.get_response()

    conv.send_message('Please tell me your name')
    name = conv.get_response().raw_text
    while not any(x.isalpha() for x in name):
        conv.send_message("Your name didn't have any letters! Try again")
        name = conv.get_response().raw_text

    conv.send_message('Thanks {}!'.format(name))
```

But it wont run. In the docs is written that chat stands for an entity. So I tried the sender id and the username...

My Code:

```
@bot.on(events.NewMessage(chats=bot.get_entity('Just Another Test Group'),blacklist_chats=True,pattern='/access'))
async def access(event):
    print("jop")
    temp = await event.get_sender()
    temp2 = await event.get_chat()
    print(temp)
    print(temp2.id)
    with bot.conversation(temp.id) as conv:
        print("started")
        event.respond("hmm")
        conv.send_message('Hi!')
        hello = conv.get_response()

        conv.send_message('Please tell me your name')
        name = conv.get_response().raw_text
        while not any(x.isalpha() for x in name):
            conv.send_message("Your name didn't have any letters! Try again")
            name = conv.get_response().raw_text

        conv.send_message('Thanks {}!'.format(name))
```

EDIT:

I have activate logging and changed a little the code, because I guess the main issue is about that the with have to be async and the coroutines have to be awaited... It works better but still habe problems

The code:

```
@bot.on(events.NewMessage(chats=bot.get_entity('Just Another Test Group'),blacklist_chats=True,pattern='/access'))
    async def access(event):
temp = await event.get_sender()
    temp2 = await event.get_chat()
    print(temp)
    print(temp2.id)
    async with bot.conversation(temp.id) as conv:
        print("started")
        await event.respond("hmm")
        await conv.send_message('Hi!')
        # await hello = conv.get_response()
```

When I uncomment the last comment I get the error:

```
await hello = conv.get_response()
    ^
SyntaxError: cannot assign to await expression
```

If I dont await this I get:

```
 'wait_for' was never awaited
  await callback(event)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

Also I have using a logger, but dont know what to do about this messages:

```
started
DEBUG:telethon.extensions.messagepacker:Assigned msg_id = 6882318088190017728 to SendMessageRequest (216c20ca460)
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Encrypting 1 message(s) in 60 bytes for sending
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Encrypted messages put in a queue to be sent
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Waiting for messages to send...
DEBUG:telethon.extensions.messagepacker:Assigned msg_id = 6882318088190017732 to MsgsAck (216c20ca970)
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Encrypting 1 message(s) in 44 bytes for sending
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Encrypted messages put in a queue to be sent
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Waiting for messages to send...
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Handling RPC result for message 6882318088190017728
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Receiving items from the network...
DEBUG:telethon.extensions.messagepacker:Assigned msg_id = 6882318088584285764 to SendMessageRequest (216c206bb50)
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Encrypting 1 message(s) in 60 bytes for sending
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Encrypted messages put in a queue to be sent
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Waiting for messages to send...
DEBUG:telethon.extensions.messagepacker:Assigned msg_id = 6882318088584285768 to MsgsAck (216c20ca130)
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Encrypting 1 message(s) in 36 bytes for sending
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Encrypted messages put in a queue to be sent
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Waiting for messages to send...
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Handling RPC result for message 6882318088584285764
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Receiving items from the network...
DEBUG:telethon.extensions.messagepacker:Assigned msg_id = 6882318088923057584 to SendMessageRequest (216c20ca220)
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Encrypting 1 message(s) in 64 bytes for sending
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Encrypted messages put in a queue to be sent
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Waiting for messages to send...
DEBUG:telethon.extensions.messagepacker:Assigned msg_id = 6882318088923057588 to MsgsAck (216c20cac40)
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Encrypting 1 message(s) in 36 bytes for sending
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Encrypted messages put in a queue to be sent
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Waiting for messages to send...
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Handling RPC result for message 6882318088923057584
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Receiving items from the network...
DEBUG:telethon.extensions.messagepacker:Assigned msg_id = 6882318225772327524 to PingRequest (216c206b430)
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Encrypting 1 message(s) in 28 bytes for sending
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Encrypted messages put in a queue to be sent
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Waiting for messages to send...
DEBUG:telethon.extensions.messagepacker:Assigned msg_id = 6882318225926609140 to MsgsAck (216c2055c40)
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Encrypting 1 message(s) in 36 bytes for sending
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Encrypted messages put in a queue to be sent
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Waiting for messages to send...
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Handling pong for message 6882318225772327524
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Receiving items from the network...
DEBUG:telethon.extensions.messagepacker:Assigned msg_id = 6882318483466030832 to PingRequest (216c206baf0)
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Encrypting 1 message(s) in 28 bytes for sending
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Encrypted messages put in a queue to be sent
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Waiting for messages to send...
DEBUG:telethon.extensions.messagepacker:Assigned msg_id = 6882318483476936100 to MsgsAck (216c206b9a0)
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Encrypting 1 message(s) in 36 bytes for sending
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Encrypted messages put in a queue to be sent
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Waiting for messages to send...
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Handling pong for message 6882318483466030832
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Receiving items from the network...
DEBUG:telethon.extensions.messagepacker:Assigned msg_id = 6882318741250045192 to PingRequest (216c206b880)
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Encrypting 1 message(s) in 28 bytes for sending
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Encrypted messages put in a queue to be sent
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Waiting for messages to send...
DEBUG:telethon.extensions.messagepacker:Assigned msg_id = 6882318741262651816 to MsgsAck (216c206b430)
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Encrypting 1 message(s) in 36 bytes for sending
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Encrypted messages put in a queue to be sent
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Waiting for messages to send...
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Handling pong for message 6882318741250045192
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Receiving items from the network...
DEBUG:telethon.extensions.messagepacker:Assigned msg_id = 6882318998993130716 to PingRequest (216c206ba60)
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Encrypting 1 message(s) in 28 bytes for sending
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Encrypted messages put in a queue to be sent
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Waiting for messages to send...
DEBUG:telethon.extensions.messagepacker:Assigned msg_id = 6882318999009786636 to MsgsAck (216c206baf0)
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Encrypting 1 message(s) in 36 bytes for sending
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Encrypted messages put in a queue to be sent
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Waiting for messages to send...
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Handling pong for message 6882318998993130716
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Receiving items from the network...
DEBUG:telethon.extensions.messagepacker:Assigned msg_id = 6882319256720751452 to PingRequest (216c206b820)
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Encrypting 1 message(s) in 28 bytes for sending
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Encrypted messages put in a queue to be sent
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Waiting for messages to send...
DEBUG:telethon.extensions.messagepacker:Assigned msg_id = 6882319256729883836 to MsgsAck (216c206b880)
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Encrypting 1 message(s) in 36 bytes for sending
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Encrypted messages put in a queue to be sent
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Waiting for messages to send...
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Handling pong for message 6882319256720751452
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Receiving items from the network...
DEBUG:telethon.extensions.messagepacker:Assigned msg_id = 6882319514437753024 to PingRequest (216c206ba30)
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Encrypting 1 message(s) in 28 bytes for sending
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Encrypted messages put in a queue to be sent
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Waiting for messages to send...
DEBUG:telethon.extensions.messagepacker:Assigned msg_id = 6882319514450436892 to MsgsAck (216c206ba60)
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Encrypting 1 message(s) in 36 bytes for sending
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Encrypted messages put in a queue to be sent
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Waiting for messages to send...
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Handling pong for message 6882319514437753024
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Receiving items from the network...
DEBUG:telethon.extensions.messagepacker:Assigned msg_id = 6882319772162655792 to PingRequest (216c206bfd0)
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Encrypting 1 message(s) in 28 bytes for sending
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Encrypted messages put in a queue to be sent
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Waiting for messages to send...
DEBUG:telethon.extensions.messagepacker:Assigned msg_id = 6882319772173152884 to MsgsAck (216c206b820)
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Encrypting 1 message(s) in 36 bytes for sending
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Encrypted messages put in a queue to be sent
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Waiting for messages to send...
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Handling pong for message 6882319772162655792
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Receiving items from the network...
DEBUG:telethon.extensions.messagepacker:Assigned msg_id = 6882320029904364204 to PingRequest (216c206be80)
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Encrypting 1 message(s) in 28 bytes for sending
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Encrypted messages put in a queue to be sent
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Waiting for messages to send...
DEBUG:telethon.extensions.messagepacker:Assigned msg_id = 6882320029914435004 to MsgsAck (216c206ba30)
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Encrypting 1 message(s) in 36 bytes for sending
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Encrypted messages put in a queue to be sent
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Waiting for messages to send...
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Handling pong for message 6882320029904364204
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Receiving items from the network...
```

Regards and thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "wont run"? The code may be running but causing an error you don't see (you need to enable `logging`). Or, if the code really is not running, make sure you're getting the event at all for the handler to run.

Comment: @Lonami Thank you. Did what you say and edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Omg ... Im sorry. It is about the Telegram Web.

When I using my phone or the desktop app I reseave everything perfectly...

Im sorry for that.